# Angular JS routing: get URL to stay as user inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app that lets users create polls, then link that poll to other users for them to vote.

To let users give a direct link, I need two route parameters: the ID of the user who made the poll, and the poll question.

So I want to let users go to website.com/:id/:question, and then make the corresponding API get calls using those parameters to get the information.

However, the page always redirects to website.com/ no matter what is put in.

Any ideas of where I would go to change this?

EDIT://

The $routeParams seems to be the right idea!

However, I am having trouble making it work.

I set it up like so:

```
angular.module('voteApp')
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller : 'MainCtrl'
      })

      .when ('/:id/:poll', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller : 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Then the client side console keeps printing 'Tried to load angular more than once'
And when I switch the index.html to 'app/main/main.jade' it just prints the contents of that file.

I am fairly sure that the path to index.html is correct, since the path to main.jade is correct and I am basing the path to index.html relatively to that

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried? Please visit the [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for some tips.

Comment: I really didn't know what part of the code to post for this question, I'm pretty new to MEAN stack in general. Here is the client side app code however, it is probable in here: https://github.com/rmarren1/vote/tree/master/client/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NgRoute, you ought to use the `$routeParams` service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

If you are using ui-Router, then you can use the `$stateParams` service: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateparams-1

You would also need to define a route/state to correspond to the path `/:id/:question` as well.